#  How to retrieve the value of a number of properties?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

1. I have a List collection that hold a number of property names.
2. MyViewModel is a class that holds all possible properties to be shown on a view.
3. Now I would like go through a collection of MyViewModel and only get the values of all those properties that were defined previously in step 1).

I think I have to use reflection.

I could get the property name like this:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

However how do I now utilise this further to go through the collection and get the values for only the properties I have defined in step 1?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a property name you need to do ( roughly - I cannot test it out ATM )

```
thing.GetType().Properties(propname).GetValue(thing,null);
```

which should return you the value of the 'propname' property on the 'thing' object.

Comment: The right code would be. rowViewModel.GetType().GetProperty("FieldName").GetValue(rowViewModel, null); Thank you very much for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: My pleasure. Thank you for posting the corrected code, for future searchers.